What does a leading colon in a sh script line means?
Looking inside macOS Homebrew installed cask Emacs file named emacs-nw used to start Emacs in terminal mode, I see the following script (see below).

What does the colon (':') at the start of the line 8 of this script mean?

The line is: : "${orig:=$0}"
I am aware of the substitutions inside the ${} macro, but not familiar with the leading : on that line.
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                         
#                                                                                                                                 
# Use this file as a symlink target to easily create a "terminal only" emacs:                                                     
#   ln -s /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/emacs-nw /usr/local/bin/emacs                                                    
#                                                                                                                                 

orig=$(readlink "$0")
: "${orig:=$0}" # Otherwise you can't run it directly                                                                             
exec "${orig%/*}"/Emacs -nw "$@"


On a macOS Sonoma, where GNU Bash 3.2.57 (an old version) is used as sh, the invoked help command issued from within sh (which is that old version of bash) describes it as: "No effect; the command does nothing.  A zero exit code is returned.".
From Bash 5.2.26, the message is similar but formatted differently:
:: :
    Null command.
    
    No effect; the command does nothing.
    
    Exit Status:
    Always succeeds.

Under zsh (where you have to use run-help) the message is also similar but again formatted differently:
: [ arg ... ]
       This  command  does nothing, although normal argument expansions
       is performed which may have effects on shell parameters.  A zero
       exit status is returned.

So this would seem to indicate that it only exists to allow the substitution logic,
inside "${orig:=$0}" to be done, so that if the command that invoked the script is a symlink, the link expanded path is used, otherwise the path identified by $0 is used.
The next line extract the path of the command, removing the last part with "${orig%/*}".
The overall script builds the complete path of the Emacs binary handling any symbolic links.

@Chris Davies Note that I did not issue it from bash.  That's why I explicitly mentioned sh .  I also tested it under Bash, and the output means the same but is not what I printed in my answer.  On macOS sh is implemented as an older version of Bash, and on my macOS Sonoma I installed the latest version of Bash, so the the output is not the same.  Therefore the description you updated is still not exactly correct.

@PRouleau thank you for correcting my misunderstanding. +1 to you
